# Find a list of users with duplicate transactions

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
Transaction_ID  int(9)  NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
Datetime    date    NO      NULL     
Giver_ID    int(9)  NO      NULL     
Recipient_ID    int(9)  NO      NULL     
Points  int(4)  NO      NULL     
Category_ID int(3)  NO      NULL     
Reason  text    NO      NULL
```

Apparently I've managed to award some of our students double points for "Behaviour Week".

I would like a list of all the rows in this `transactions` table where a single user (`Recipient_ID`) has more than one transaction with `Category_ID = 16`.

**Each `Recipient ID` should only have ONE transaction with `Category_ID = 16`.**

For example, if I had...

```
54784   2012-02-01  138573  137444  100 16  You have done very well in Behaviour Week! Because...
55040   2012-02-01  138573  132629  100 16  You have done very well in Behaviour Week! Because...
```

That's two separate users, which is fine.

However, if I find...

```
54784   2012-02-01  138573  137444  100 16  You have done very well in Behaviour Week! Because...
55040   2012-02-01  138573  137444  100 16  You have done very well in Behaviour Week! Because...
```

Then I've made a mistake and I need to delete one of those rows.

Could someone please suggest a query which will list all of these potentially incorrect transactions? I'd prefer for them just to be "SELECT" so that I can manually check rather than blindly DELETE-ing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find Recipients IDs which have more than 1 transaction for category 16 you can use the following:

```
select Recipient_ID,
       Count(Transaction_ID) as [Transactions]
from myTable
where Category_ID = 16
group by Recipient_ID
having Count(Transaction_ID) > 1
```

If you want to really put your mind at rest, remove the Having clause:

```
select Recipient_ID,
       Count(Transaction_ID) as [Transactions]
from myTable
where Category_ID = 16
group by Recipient_ID
```

You can then see the number of transactions against each recipient ID and satisfy yourself that it is really 1 for each

Comment: Hi Macros. `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0338 sec )`. Then again, I've just tried the others' answers and I'm having the same problem.. so I'm wondering if I actually haven't made any mistakes after all!

Comment: Yeah, looks like that's exactly the case. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: If you are getting zero rows then looks like you haven't made a mistake.  I've updated my answer to show another way of checking

Comment: Perfect - I haven't made any mistakes after all. Why do I listen to my students?!?

Answer (score 2):

You can use grouping and having:

```
select count (transaction_id), recipient_id
from thetable
where category_id = 16
group by recipient_id
having count(transaction_id) > 1
```

The `having` clause is very much like the `where` clause but it operates on rows *after* grouping has taken place. In other words, `where` is a pre-grouping filter and `having` is a post-grouping filter.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Recipient_ID, COUNT(*)
from transactions
where Category_ID = 16
group by Recipient_ID
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE category_id = 16 GROUP BY recipient_id HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

This will show only those users who have more than one of these entries